# How to rename labels and title in seaborn scatterplot legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, subplot

I have the following legend that I'd like to change:

[image]

I'd like to change the titles from `State` to `Place` and `Transition` to `Kilometers` and the labels underneath `State` need to change from `0` to `City`, `1` to `Rural`, and `2` to `Other`. I'd also like to change `Transition` values to integers instead of floats. Furthermore, I'd like to have the new titles in bold and oriented to the left side instead of right above the values.

I am not sure if all this is even possible and how to best go about this...

I obtained this legend by running the following code (bear in mind that this plot is part of `ax2`):

```
sns.scatterplot(data = data, x = 'x', y = 'y', size = 'Transition', hue = 'State', palette = 'flare', ax = ax2, legend = 'full')
ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 1), loc = 2, borderaxespad = 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simplest to alter `data` with the desired values: [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the places and convert the kilometers with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html).

If you prefer to keep `data` intact, [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the changes inside the plot call:

```
places = {0: 'City', 1: 'Rural', 2: 'Other'}

sns.scatterplot(data=data.assign(Place=data['State'].map(places), Kilometers=data['Transition'].astype(int)),
                x='x', y='y', size='Kilometers', hue='Place', palette='flare', ax=ax2, legend='full')
```

Or you can make the changes in-place beforehand:

```
data = data.rename(columns={'State': 'Place', 'Transition': 'Kilometers'})
data['Place'] = data['Place'].map({0: 'City', 1: 'Rural', 2: 'Other'})
data['Kilometers'] = data['Kilometers'].astype(int)

sns.scatterplot(data=data, x='x', y='y', size='Kilometers', hue='Place', palette='flare', ax=ax2, legend='full')
```

---

> What about making the legend titles (`Place` and `Kilometers`) bold and slightly larger, and also maybe leftward shifted?

It seems seaborn reconstructs the legend manually, so those titles are not true `title` objects. I'm not sure if there's a better way, but you can replace your current `ax2.legend(...)` call with something like this:

```
# first remove the line: ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0)

# then get the existing seaborn legend and alter it
leg2 = ax2.get_legend()
leg2.set_bbox_to_anchor((1.05, 1))
for t in leg2.get_texts():
    if t.get_text() in ['Place', 'Kilometers']:
        t.set_weight('bold')
        t.set_fontsize('large')
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpfull reply! What about making the legend titles ('Place' and 'Kilometers') bold and slightly larger. I tried it with ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.01, 1), loc = 2, borderaxespad = 0, title_fontsize = 16) but that didn't work...

Comment: and also maybe leftward shifted.?

Comment: `pd.Categorical.from_codes(data['State'].astype(int), ['City', 'Rural', 'Other'])` could also be considered.

Comment: @JonnDough Not sure if there's a better way, but I added one option to format the seaborn legend (it seems the normal matplotlib ways don't work because seaborn does its own thing).

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, good idea.

Comment: Note that the latest seaborn 0.11.2 has a new function `sns.move_legend(...)` to move its position (e.g. `sns.move_legend(ax2, bbox_to_anchor=..., loc='upper left')`).  Also note that it is recommended to use the descriptive strings instead of the numbers for the `loc=` argument.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for your suggestions. I will check out sns.move_legend(...)!

Comment: After `sns.move_legend`, the (pseudo) titles are no longer left-aligned anymore. I'm not sure exactly what seaborn is doing under the hood.

Comment: Maybe @JohanC knows how to solve that 'issue'? Otherwise, I'll use your suggested solution.

Comment: @tdy Is there also a way that I can get State and Horizontal next to eachother (horizontally) instead of vertically with your implementation? I tried to do legend._ncol(2) but that didn't work...